# Unable to load the AWS ELB on 443 port but able to access ELB url on 80 port

Tags: apache-httpd, aws, virtual-host, aws-elb

I have 2 webservers under AWS ELB. Each webserver has one virtual host file and bundle.crt, .key files. When I tried to load the ELB with http then its directing to the webservers fine but when I use https://ELB url then I am getting below error.

[image]

I am tried various options to troubleshoot this issue. I changed the certificates in webserver, I changed the listener ports on the ELB servers, I checked the security group of instances and ELB, I verified the httpd.conf file, verified ssl_conf file but I didnt find any server level error or misconfigurations. All seems to be good at server level but still I am facing above issue. When I tested my web url in ssltest site then I got "The secure protocol is not support" error. I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: `telnet <url> 443` What does that tell you?

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the security group of instances and ELB

Did you add this as an inbound rule for your instances? If not, add and retry.

```
HTTPS           443     HTTP        80      <name of the certificate>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your ELB respond to https requests you need to have a listener configured for the port. You did not say if you are using a Classic Load Balancer or the newer ELB.

You need to add X.509 certificate to the load balancer and you can use it to terminate your SSL connections, however, it also provides you the option to keep the connection secured to the end point Web Servers.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html#https-ssl-listeners